# GDB says there is no symbol table available even when a separate debug file is loaded?

Tags: debugging, gdb, coredump

I'm debugging a core file with a crash in function `foo` from `libA.so`. I have `libA.so.debug` in another directory. I load it in gdb via `add-symbol-file path/to/libA.so.debug`, gdb loads it. After that, if I do `info symbol foo` it correctly states that it's a function from `libA.so.debug` and if I do `i scope foo` I see all the debug info for function args/locals listed. However, when I go to the frame in the backtrace with `foo` and do `info args` (or locals), gdb complains that `No symbol table info available.`.
If, after that, I do `i symbol $rip`, it prints that this is a function `foo` from libA.so.

Why doesn't GDB pick up the debuginfo from the .debug file and how to make it use the available symbol able for the backtrace?

Note, that if I copy `libA.so.debug` to the folder with `libA.so` it seems to work automatically, but this is not possible in general for my use case, and I don't understand why it should be required.